# Regex: Only match non-nested groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text, in a similar pattern to:

```
new{test}anotherone{test{nest}}new1{test1}new2{test2}
```

I'm new to Regex, and trying to create a pattern which matches groups such that for each match:
Group 1: new
Group 2: test

I have this working with `([\S][a-z#-()->]+)\{([^?+]*?)\}` using JavaScript

However, I want to ignore the block with the nesting, such that the `anotherone{test{nest}}` is ignored from the matching. Here's my attempt on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IQfO06/1)

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
The string might also have nested inside the nested part, e.g.

```
new{test}ignore_this{test1{test1}{test2{test2}}new{test}new{test}
```

Such that it should only match: Group1: new / Group2: test

Comment: Try `\b(?<![{}])(\w+)\{([^{}]*)\}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQfO06/2).

Comment: You might also get the 2 matches at the end using a negative lookahead at the end `([^\s{}]+)\{([^{}]*)}(?!})` https://regex101.com/r/CSrZWq/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex to match **each pair** of `new` and `test` (3 pairs in your input):

```
(?<!{)\b([^{}]+){([^{}]*)}(?![^{}]*})
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQfO06/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!{)`: Make sure we don't have `{` at previous position
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `([^{}]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `{` and `}` in group #1
- `{`: Match a `{`
- `([^{}]*)`: Match 0+ of any character that is not `{` and `}` in group #2
- `}`: Match a `}`
- `(?![^{}]*})`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a closing `}` ahead without any `{` and `}` in between

Comment: Thanks! What if the string had nesting inside it? E.g. ```new{test}ignore_this{test1{test1}{test2{test2}}new{test}new{test}``` and I want to ignore the entire ```ignore_this{test1{test1}{test2{test2}}```? I can update the question to reflect this edge case :)

Comment: @o1n3n21: Did you get a chance to try my updated answer? Also don't understand reason of a downvote here.

Comment: Thanks I just accepted the answer, and didn't downvote, unsure where that came from. Thanks again for your help!